# highchart - how to encapsulate multiple series to one series as their parent

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do you encapsulate multiple series to one series only as their parent container?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/robertpeter07/hNkAA/6/

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#1c3340', '#94b05a', '#386580', '#e8d78c', '#6c5f36', '#899fa8']
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            setToMargin: 50
        },
        title: {
            text: null 
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            categories: ['Jan 2014', 'Feb 2014']
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: true,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 1,
            tickWidth: 1,
            ceiling: 100,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}%'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 0,
            y: 100,
            itemMarginTop: 10,
            itemMarginBottom: 10
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                grouping: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    inside: false,
                    format: '{y}%',
                    color: '#000000'
                },
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        //statement to disable clickevent of time off and GRM Delta
                    }

                }
                //pointWidth: 30
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'data1',
            data: [-12, -10],
            stack: 0,
            index: 1,
            //legendIndex: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, {
            name: 'data2',
            data: [-12, -10],
            stack: 0,
            index: 0,
            //legendIndex: 1
        }, {
            name: 'data3',
            data: [12, 17],
            stack: 1
        }, {
            name: 'data4',
            data: [8, 3],
            stack: 2
        }, {
            name: 'data5',
            data: [-13, -11],
            stack: 3
        }, {
            name: 'data6',
            data: [14, 13],
            stack: 4
        }]
    });
});
```

- The first set should be at 0%, just an example
- The second set should be at 15 or 20%

Does anyone have a suggestion to accomplish this?

To be specific here is the sample image: 
[image: Sample multiple series image]

Comment: This makes little sense unfortunately. Where are you getting the values you are suggesting of `0%` and `15% or 20%` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's not easy task but possible to achieve. Crucial option is `threshold` which sets translation you need. However, only one threshold per series is supported. Then to overcome that issue, we will use for each category different series, but connected to the first one using `linkedTo`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hNkAA/7/

In short, main series:

```
    {
        name: 'data1',
        id: 'data1', //set ID for children series
        data: [-12], //one series = one point for category
        stack: 0,
        index: 1,
        //legendIndex: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
```

And connected series with different starting point:

```
    {
        threshold: 10, //base for that series will be 10, not default 0
        name: 'data1', 
        linkedTo: 'data1', //link to master series
        data: [[1, -10]], //set point only for second category
        stack: 0,
        index: 0,
        //legendIndex: 1
    }
```

Comment: thanks! but one more problem the child set should not follow what is in the y-axis tick positions, only the parent. is there anything I can do with that?

Comment: How do you determine position of children? Using threshold is the only option to translate series (I don't about any kind of hacks of course). You can translate somehow (maybe using yAxis.toValue() ?) offset from parent series to threshold option.

Comment: in child set, if it is negative its position goes down, if it is positive the position goes up but does not rely in y-axis, only parent should follow y-axis values.